# C# WPF. How to filter List<int>

Tags: c#, wpf

i have two list want to compare and then filter it.
so if list1 contains 1,2,3,4 and list2 2,4 i want to filter list and leave only 1 and 3

```
HProDataContext db = new HProDataContext();


        List<int> _AllRoomsID = (from d in db.rooms select d.id).ToList();
        List<int> _ClosedRoomsID = (from d in db.checkinouts select d.roomid).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < _ClosedRoomsID.Count; i++)
        {
            if (_AllRoomsID.Contains(_ClosedRoomsID[i]) == true)
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var OpenRooms = AllRoomsID.Except(ClosedRoomsID);
```

Or, if you don't want an IEnumearble:

```
List<int> OpenRooms = AllRoomsID.Except(ClosedRoomsID).ToList();
```